# Magento 2 - read and write new customer attribute

Tags: magento2, attributes, customer, eav

I added a new customer attribute `n2gEmails`:

**app/code/Fekete/Newsletter2Go/etc/extension_attributes.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Api/etc/extension_attributes.xsd">
    <extension_attributes for="Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface">
        <attribute code="n2gEmails" type="string"/>
    </extension_attributes>
</config>
```

**app/code/Fekete/Newsletter2Go/Setup/Patch/Data/AddN2gEmailsCustomerAttribute.php**:

```
<?php

namespace Fekete\Newsletter2Go\Setup\Patch\Data;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\DataPatchInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\PatchRevertableInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;
use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetup;

class AddN2gEmailsCustomerAttribute implements DataPatchInterface, PatchRevertableInterface
{

    /**
     * @var ModuleDataSetupInterface
     */
    private $moduleDataSetup;
    /**
     * @var CustomerSetup
     */
    private $customerSetupFactory;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup
     * @param CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup,
        CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
    ) {
        $this->moduleDataSetup = $moduleDataSetup;
        $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function apply()
    {
        $this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection()->startSetup();
        /** @var CustomerSetup $customerSetup */
        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $this->moduleDataSetup]);
        $customerSetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY,
            'n2gEmails',
            [
                'type' => 'varchar',
                'label' => 'Newsletter2Go Emails',
                'input' => 'text',
                'source' => '',
                'required' => false,
                'visible' => true,
                'position' => 333,
                'system' => false,
                'backend' => ''
            ]
        );

        $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute('customer', 'n2gEmails')->addData([
            'used_in_forms' => [
                'adminhtml_customer',
                'customer_account_create',
                'customer_account_edit'
            ]
        ]);
        $attribute->save();

        $this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection()->endSetup();
    }

    public function revert()
    {
        $this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection()->startSetup();
        /** @var CustomerSetup $customerSetup */
        $customerSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $this->moduleDataSetup]);
        $customerSetup->removeAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, 'n2gEmails');

        $this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection()->endSetup();
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getAliases()
    {
        return [];
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public static function getDependencies()
    {
        return [

        ];
    }



}
```

Then I executed `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`.

How can I access this attribute now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example shows how you can access the attribute from a helper.

**app\code\Fekete\Newsletter2Go\Helper\Data.php**

```
namespace Fekete\Newsletter2Go\Helper;

use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper;

class Data extends AbstractHelper
{

    private $session;
    private $customer;
    private $n2g_emails;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context
       ,\Magento\Customer\Model\Session $session
    ) {

        $this->session = $session;
        $this->customer = $session->getCustomer();
        $this->n2g_emails = $this->customer->getN2gEmails();
    }

...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

$customerSession = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');  

if ($customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {

$customerFactory = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory')>create();

$customer = $customerFactory->load($customerSession->getCustomerId());

$newattr=$customer->getN2gEmails();

//echo $newattr;

}
```

**" Hope This Will Help You !!!"**

Comment: Nah, this is not the supposed way how to do it, it is really dirty code.